# Reputation suddenly decreased by 4

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Not that the reputation is really important to me, but I am wondering if there's a little bug. Today (starting with 503 rep), I edited a question, which seemed not to be accepted. However, after that, I answered a question. As soon as the answer was posted, there was already a down-vote. So the reputation went down to 501. Like a minute after that, the down-vote disappeared. When I checked the reputation again, it was 499. Why is this? Do I lose reputation, if a reputation-giving component by myself gets removed?

Comment: your rep is actally at 501.

Comment: yes, I edited a question before. This was accepted during posting my question

Comment: I just added all of the reputation on your profile, and got 501 as it currently says. Maybe something you edited was deleted? Go to your [reputation page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1339620/valentino-ru?tab=reputation) and check the "Show removed posts" box at the bottom, and see if something else shows up for today.